# Signature Verification

Tags: image, matlab, authentication, azure-cognitive-services, electronic-signature

I'm investigating about what would be a valid approach in order to provide a method to **verify** a **user** operation by his **signature**. The application must verify the user through it's fingertip signature, upon a particular action to be executed by him.

For the record, the user wil be previously signed in to the platform, this signature would be srot of a *second factor authetication*.

So far, I got two approches in mind:

- The first one is not really good: [Custom Vision](http://customvision.ai). This service is
  for classification, not verification, so it's a dead end.
- On a second approach, I found MatLab exercises claiming to have a
  solution, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWvImUJnKKA) youtube video explain (which seems to be quite
  experimental and unofficial).

Comment: So you're basically looking for a service that will compute the similarity of two images?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari yes. But it must be quite precise, since it's not classification but verification.

Comment: @downvoter, please at least comment what's wrong with the question.